# Kendo Scheduler: Customize Recurrence Editor

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, editor, scheduler, recurrence

There is no documentation for this. I would like to replace the drop down for selecting recurrence type: 'Never', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Yearly'

to radio buttons.

I am using Kendo Scheduler for MVC if you're able to provide instructions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this. Basically you should inspect the RecurrenceEditor source code and extend it to override the desired parts.